# How to get the last part of the current URL in ant design

Tags: reactjs, ant-design-pro

I'm making an edit form in ant design and I want to get the id passed from the following route in the component

```
      {
        path: '/post/edit/:id',
        name: 'edit',
        hideInMenu: true,
        component: './Post/PostForm'
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following function:

```
export function getLastPart() {
  const parts = window.location.href.split('/');
  return parts[parts.length - 1];
}
```

Then, in the component, you need to check that the last part is an actual ID. I, for instance, use UUIDs, so I also use the following function:

```
const uuidReg = /^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/i;

export function isUuid(path) {
  return uuidReg.test(path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ant-design pro with umijs, you can get params as below

```
import {useParams} from 'umi';


const PostForm = () => {
   const params = useParams();
   return (<> {JSON.stringify(params)} </>) 
}
```